# Append/delete items from array in php/html file

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am a PHP beginner and need some help.

I have a `config.data` file that has the $logins array serialized in it. (thanks @Barmar!) 
I have `signin.php` (below) which I would like to modify in the following way:

1. Add a 'add project' button which would append the info to the $logins array
2. Add a 'delete project' button which would delete the info to the $logins array.

Any help to accomplish these two goals would be appreciated!

`config.data`:

```
$logins = array(
'project1' =>
        array(
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'title' => 'Capacitors Project Planner',
        'emails' => array('myweb@mywebsite.com')
         ),
'project2' =>
    array(
        'password' => 'mypassword2',
        'title' => 'My second project',
        'emails' => array('manager@youwebsite.com',
                        'worker@youwebsite.com')
        )
);
```

`signin.php`:

```
require_once( 'config.php' );
//displays arrays
<table class="table" border='1'>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th> Project name</th>
    <th> Project Login</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach( $logins as $projname => $projinfos ): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $projname ?></td>
        <td><?= $projinfos["title"]?>
        </td>
        </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example :-

> `array_push()` treats `array` as a stack, and pushes the passed variables
>   onto the end of `array`. The length of `array` increases by the number of
>   variables pushed.
>
> ```
> <?php
> $stack = array("orange", "banana");
> array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
> print_r($stack);
> ?>
> ```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

To delete elements from an array

```
<?php
$x = array(5, 6);
unset($x[0]);
var_dump($x);
?>

… this yields:

array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(6)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put PHP code into the file, serialize the data and read/write that.

To get the current value of the array, use:

```
$logins = unserialize(file_get_contents("config.data"));
```

After you update `$logins`, you can save it with:

```
file_put_contents("config.data", serialize($logins));
```

Comment: It goes in the script that displays the form, and in the script that updates the file when the user submits the form. These might be the same script.

Comment: Ahh gotcha - so I updated the config.php to remove the array and put the array into config.data file.
Now I need to figure out how to add a form...